# SQL COUNT query returning NULL when using temporary table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using the following code to try to return the average revenue based on the number of songs in an album.

```
WITH Album_Tracks AS (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS "#ofTracks", SUM(invoice_items.UnitPrice) AS "Album_Revenue"
   from tracks
   LEFT JOIN invoice_items ON invoice_items.trackID = tracks.trackID
   GROUP BY Albumid
)

SELECT #ofTracks, AVG(Album_Revenue)
FROM Album_Tracks
GROUP BY #ofTracks
ORDER BY #ofTracks DESC
```

The problem I am running into is that the "# of tracks" column in the temporary table 'Album_Tracks' returns a column of NULL values when i don't select all data from the table.

As in, doing this: `SELECT * FROM Album_Tracks` returns values, but `SELECT #ofTracks FROM Album_Tracks` returns only null values.

I'm not sure what the problem in my code is.

Expecting to see:
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL1Pw.png)

But am getting:
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM6BH.png)

First example the order by was not included.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample as tabular text and the expected  result

Comment: Added screenshots of sample data

Comment: which db  you are really using .. mysql ??? or sqlite??

Comment: Using sqlite. Sorry, I am just starting to work with sql

Comment: Try not using a special character as the beginning character of your column name.  `select count(*) as numtracks ... select numtracks from album_tracks ...`

Comment: screenshots are discouraged because we can't copy/paste for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a suggestion
try avoid not allowed char ( in table and column name)  as  `+ - ? ! * @ % ^ & # = / \ : " '`

```
  WITH Album_Tracks AS (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumOfTracks
          , SUM(invoice_items.UnitPrice) AS Album_Revenue 
      from tracks
      LEFT JOIN invoice_items ON invoice_items.trackID = tracks.trackID
      GROUP BY Albumid
  )
  SELECT NumOfTracks, AVG(Album_Revenue) F
  ROM Album_Tracks
  GROUP BY NumOfTracks
  ORDER BY NumOfTracks DESC
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I'll avoid using symbols in table/column titles going forward

Answer (score 0):

Try just a simple:

```
SELECT #ofTracks
```

It will return `NULL`.
Enclose `#ofTracks` in double quotes, or backticks or square brackets:

```
SELECT "#ofTracks", AVG(Album_Revenue) FROM Album_Tracks
GROUP BY "#ofTracks"
ORDER BY "#ofTracks" DESC
```